# Access Dropdown menu on webpage with Python

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to write a Python script that accesses a webpage (http://www.yeastgenome.org/locus/S000001142/overview) and downloads a (DNA sequence, fasta) file. The file is automatically downloaded once one clicks on a dropdown menu.

This is the dropdown menu:

Download (.fsa)

and one of the options would for example be:

Genomic DNA +/- 1kb

Could someone please point me in the right direction, how to do this?

The Selenium modules?

Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to navigate to the page, click on the dropdown to open it, and then click on the selection you want. You will need a couple waits... one to wait for the bottom of the page to load and show the dropdown and another short pause to wait for the dropdown to open.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver.get("http://www.yeastgenome.org/locus/S000001142/overview")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 4)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.dropdown"))).click()
option = "Protein" // change to the desired option in the dropdown... must be EXACT text
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//ul[contains(@class,'open')]/li/a[text()='" + option + "']"))).click()
```

Comment: Any comments on the downvotes? This code works in Java... I just converted it to python.

Comment: I know the reason..there are many mistakes in your provided code, problem at last line you are expecting `cssSelector` but providing `xpath`..and it's `By.CSS_SELECTOR` instead of `By.CSS` and you have not defined what is `EC` as well, I know it's `expected_conditions as EC` but OP never know without defining it..Hope you understand the reason....:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Thanks for the explanation. I didn't realize I made so many mistakes. I don't use python so I have no way to verify. I must have referenced and copied some code from another source that was bad. I fixed it now.

Comment: No problem. I have also fixed down vote.. thanks for asking about down vote...:)